# How to make outgoing calls?

Tags: android, call

I just started to write an app, that do outgoing calls.
Now I stuck in the process to make the call. 
the only way I found at the monent to hand the call over to the phone app.
But I want to do it from wwith in my app.

Does anyone have a hint, how this can be done.

Greetings Richard

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"yourPhone"));
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    layoutcall.setOnClickListener(view -> {
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
      }
      startActivity(callIntent);
    });
```

and add below line to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I found out, that it is possible to define an different dialer call screen. 
But I don't find any description, how to do it.

Does anyone have information's on that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I start to understand.

I made a mistake in explaining, what I meant.

With the dialer interface, I meant the calling interface and the possibility to create an own one or to change the layout, that it fits my suggestions.

I think, that this is not possible. Or am I wrong?